# Difference between calling a function and callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have something like this for example. with callback=self.on_goal it calls the function on_goal without the arguments.

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.on_goal, bouncetime=10)

def on_goal(self, channel):
        logger.info("Goal {}!".format(self.team))
        self.bus.notify('goal_event', {'source': 'rpi', 'team': self.team})
```

Can I also call it like you normally would but without arguments? Like this?

```
 if inactive == True:
         inactive = False
         self.on_goal
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

A callback is just a particular *use* of a function; you pass a reference to the function as an argument, and that reference is saved to be called some time later.

In your example, you still need to *call* the function:

```
if not inactive:
    inactive = False
    self.on_goal()
```

Comment: So, all I missed were the parentheses?

Comment: Yes; you simply failed to call the function.